# python class multilevel inheritance error: not defind

Tags: python, class, oop

I am learning OOP python, getting error with multilevel inheritance.

```
class par:
    def __init__(self, vehicle):
        self.vehicle=vehicle
        
class chil(par):
    def typ(self):
        self.l=['activa','jupiter','ct100','evengers']
        if self.vehicle in l:
            self.type='two_wheeler'
        else:
            self.type='four_wheelr'
class cost(chil):
    def mony(self):
        mon=[800,700,500,1200]
        if self.type=='two_wheeler':
            i= self.l.index(self.vehicle)
            return mon[i]
        else:
            return 2500
c=cost('jupiter')

c.mony()
```

Error throwing:

AttributeError: 'cost' object has no attribute 'type'

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

1. In the `chil` class within the `typ` method, you are trying to check if `self.vehicle` is present in the list `l`, but `l` is not defined in the current scope. You should be using `self.l` instead.
2. In the `chil` class, there is a typo in setting the `four_wheelr` string. It should probably be `four_wheeler`.
3. The `typ` method in the `chil` class determines the type of vehicle but is never called. You should call this method before the `mony` method, or automatically call it in the `__init__` of the `chil` class.
4. You are trying to check the type of vehicle in the `mony` method of the `cost` class without having called the `typ` method. Therefore, the `self.type` attribute will not exist unless `typ` has been called.

Possibly a correct version of your code:

```py
class par:
    def __init__(self, vehicle):
        self.vehicle = vehicle

class chil(par):
    def __init__(self, vehicle):
        super().__init__(vehicle)
        self.typ()

    def typ(self):
        self.l = ['activa', 'jupiter', 'ct100', 'evengers']
        if self.vehicle in self.l:
            self.type = 'two_wheeler'
        else:
            self.type = 'four_wheeler'

class cost(chil):
    def mony(self):
        mon = [800, 700, 500, 1200]
        if self.type == 'two_wheeler':
            i = self.l.index(self.vehicle)
            return mon[i]
        else:
            return 2500

c = cost('jupiter')
print(c.mony())
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good form to initialise the attributes that you are using *in the constructor*.

Something like ...

```
class chil(par):
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = ['activa','jupiter','ct100','evengers']
        self.type = None
```

... ensures that the attributes have some definition whenever `chil` is used.

The `AttributeError` mentioned is likely to occur because `chil.typ` has never been called. I can't see any evidence of `typ` being called before `cost.mony` is called.